# Adding buttons to the export menu in highcharts with R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How could new items be added to the export menu in highcharts, this is the code I have so far, it does not return an error that I can understand. I am trying very hard to learn highcharts.

```
jsCodeAddButtons <- JS("function() {

 var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
     
 buttons.push({
  separator: true
 });
     
 buttons.push({
  text: 'Ocultar Leyenda',
  onclick: function() {
   var chart = this;
   chart.legend.update({enabled: false});
   chart.redraw();
  }
 });

 buttons.push({
  text: 'Mostrar Leyenda',
  onclick: function() {
   var chart = this;
   chart.legend.update({enabled: true});
   chart.redraw();
  }
 });

 return buttons;

}")
```

```
 hc_exporting (
  buttons = list(
   contextButton = list(
    menuItems = jsCodeAddButtons
   )
 )
```